# Problem turning on Raspberry Pi 2b

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I have a Raspberry Pi 2b that I have trouble turning on

1_When I insert the SD card containing the operating system into the Raspberry Pi and connect it to the adapter, sometimes the green light turns on very dimly and the board is noisy and does not boot.

2_Sometimes the dim green light comes on and flickers but does not boot

3_Sometimes the board does not have lights at all and does not work

I tried many 5 volt adapters from 1 amp to 3 amps but it did not work

And I tested a lot of SD cards and booted it with all kinds of Razbin versions and many apps, but it didn't work.

Glad to help me

- Note: I did not find my problem in my sticky boot problem

Comment: what does this mean? ... `board is noisy`

Comment: @jsotola  Noise sounds can be heard in the CPU

Comment: that makes no real sense ... are you talking about a fan?

Comment: @jsotola  No ,Watch this: https://youtu.be/11zo6VkNSxU

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried with a known good power supply and a known good SD card then the Pi is faulty.

You will need to buy another Pi.

Comment: Is there no way to repair Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Unlikely.  You would need to find or hire an expert to find the exact failure.  It may or may not be repairable.  But the cost of hiring an expert and implementing the repair will be far higher than the cost of a new Pi.